# Formatting output of grep command

Tags: apache, formatting, grep, output

i have a webserver running with some applications. I do a grep from the server in order to see all the IP's that have been connected to the server. I achieved it but the HTML looks like this:

```
172.17.100.37 172.17.100.45 172.17.222.158
```

And I would like to see it like this:

```
172.17.100.37 
172.17.100.45 
172.17.222.158
```

To get these values I do this:

```
cmd = "grep -o '^[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' /var/log/apache2/access.log | sort | uniq "
```

Any idea about what could I do?

EDIT: The access.log shows like this:

```
172.17.222.158 - - [30/Jan/2014:09:33:11 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/right.cgi HTTP/1.1" 204  219 "http://172.17.223.72/index2.html?fname=172.17.223.75" "Mozilla/5.$
172.17.222.158 - - [30/Jan/2014:09:33:11 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/stop.cgi HTTP/1.1" 204 218 "http://172.17.223.72/index2.html?fname=172.17.223.75" "Mozilla/5.0$
172.17.222.158 - - [30/Jan/2014:09:33:12 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/right.cgi HTTP/1.1" 204 218 "http://172.17.223.72/index2.html?fname=172.17.223.75" "Mozilla/5.$
172.17.222.158 - - [30/Jan/2014:09:33:12 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/stop.cgi HTTP/1.1" 204
```

and so on...

Comment: Can you show the original `access.log` file? So that we can try to find a more compact way to get this output.

Comment: Editted mate, have a look. I just want to get the first IP of each line and add a \n between each match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tr`

```
echo "172.17.100.37 172.17.100.45 172.17.222.158" | tr ' ' '\n'
172.17.100.37
172.17.100.45
172.17.222.158
```

Using `awk`

```
cat file
172.17.222.158 - - [30/Jan/2014:09:33:11 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/right.cgi HTTP/1.1" 204  219 "http://172.17.223.72/index2.html?fname=172.17.223.75" "Mozilla/5.$
172.17.222.158 - - [30/Jan/2014:09:33:11 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/stop.cgi HTTP/1.1" 204 218 "http://172.17.223.72/index2.html?fname=172.17.223.75" "Mozilla/5.0$
172.17.222.158 - - [30/Jan/2014:09:33:12 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/right.cgi HTTP/1.1" 204 218 "http://172.17.223.72/index2.html?fname=172.17.223.75" "Mozilla/5.$
172.17.222.158 - - [30/Jan/2014:09:33:12 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/stop.cgi HTTP/1.1" 204
```

```
awk -F/ '{print $8}' file
172.17.223.72
172.17.223.72
172.17.223.72
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you paste the ouput of your grep-command into a HTML-file.
To get the linefeeds you may use the pre-tag:
**<pre>** *(your output goes here)* **</pre>**
This will show your linefeeds even in HTML.